# Cant use Intl-tel-input in two forms in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, intl-tel-input

Hey guys i am trying to use the plugin for two forms in the same page,but on the second page is just not loading the dropdown at all,this is my code..

This is my PHP Code:

```
<style>.hide { display: none; }</style>
<div class="form-group col-md-12 phoneBlock">
    <input type="tel" id="phone_number" name ="phone_number" value="<?php echo $phone ?>" class="form-control">
    <span id="valid-msg" class="hide">Valid</span>
    <span id="error-msg" class="hide"></span>
    <input type="hidden" id="country" name ="country" value="<?php echo $country ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="phone" name ="phone" value="<?php echo $phone ?>">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-loading-overlay/2.1.7/loadingoverlay.min.js" integrity="sha256-S4gG40EfG9fszyLcPdnHxrARVtHCTLYxq3Lz4h5H93E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="tel/build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
    <script src="js/phone.js"></script>
</div>
```

And this is my JS file. I dont know how to use javascript for two forms in the same page,any help will be appreciated!! Thank you!

```
var input = document.querySelector("#phone_number");
var country = document.querySelector("#country");
(errorMsg = document.querySelector("#error-msg")),
  (validMsg = document.querySelector("#valid-msg")),
  (btnSubmit = $("#btnSubmit"));

btnSubmit.attr("disabled", true);
// here, the index maps to the error code returned from getValidationError - see readme
var errorMap = [
  "Invalid number",
  "Invalid country code",
  "Too short",
  "Too long",
  "Invalid number"
];

var reset = function() {
  input.classList.remove("error");
  errorMsg.innerHTML = "";
  errorMsg.classList.add("hide");
  validMsg.classList.add("hide");
};

var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
  separateDialCode: true,
  initialCountry: "auto",
  geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
      var countryCode = resp && resp.country ? resp.country : "";
      callback(countryCode);
    });
  },
  utilsScript: "tel/build/js/utils.js?1562189064761" // just for formatting/placeholders etc
});
input.addEventListener("countrychange", function(e) {
  country.value = iti.getSelectedCountryData().iso2.toUpperCase();
});

// on blur: validate
input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  reset();

  if (input.value.trim()) {
    if (iti.isValidNumber()) {
      validMsg.classList.remove("hide");
      $("#phone").val(iti.getNumber());
      btnSubmit.attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      input.classList.add("error");
      var errorCode = iti.getValidationError();
      errorMsg.innerHTML = errorMap[errorCode];
      errorMsg.classList.remove("hide");
      btnSubmit.attr("disabled", true);
    }
  }
});

// on keyup / change flag: reset
input.addEventListener("change", reset);
input.addEventListener("keyup", reset);
```

Comment: In HTML duplicate IDs are not allowed otherwise you face problems like this one, you will need to refactor your code to accommodate two different ids like `#phone_number` and `#phone_number2` everywhere - css selectors, variable references, event handlers etc

Comment: Your php echo codes in your HTML should be closed with semi colons `<?php echo $phone ?>` should be `<?php echo $phone; ?>` or `<?=$phone?>`.

Comment: @dalelandry A semicolon is not required for the last statement in a PHP block

Answer (score 0):

IDs of the elements must be different.
I did it by this way:

```
function runIntlTelInputAndGeoIp(element, countryCallback) {
    let $countrySelect = $(element).parents('form').find("select[name='country']"),
        initialCountry = ($countrySelect.length > 0 && $countrySelect.val()) ? $countrySelect.val().toLowerCase() : "auto",
        defCountry     = 'GB';

    if (element === undefined) {
        if (typeof countryCallback === "function") {
            countryCallback(defCountry);
        }
        return;
    }

    let iti = intlTelInput(element, {
        allowDropdown: true,
        customPlaceholder: function (selectedCountryPlaceholder, selectedCountryData) {
            // return selectedCountryPlaceholder.replace(/[()\s-]/g, '');    //to show National phone number without spaces and any symbols (only +)
            return "+" + selectedCountryData.dialCode; //to show only country dialCode with plus
        },
        autoHideDialCode: false,
        initialCountry: initialCountry, //"auto",
        nationalMode: true,
        // onlyCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ch', 'ca', 'do'],
        preferredCountries: [],
        // placeholderNumberType: "MOBILE",
        separateDialCode: false,
        autoPlaceholder: 'off',
        utilsScript: "/js/intl-tel-input/utils.js?v=8.12.11"
    });
    iti.promise.then(function () {
        let countryCode = iti.getSelectedCountryData().iso2 || defCountry;
        if (typeof countryCallback === "function") {
            countryCallback(countryCode.toUpperCase());
        }
    });
    return iti;
}
$(function() {
   $("input[name='phone']").each(function () {
       runIntlTelInputAndGeoIp($(this)[0]);
    });
});
```